# scrape from descendant tags within div using bs4 in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

my code only gets as far as finding div class="league-player-tracking-shots", I've used descendants, children and contents but can't get to the bottom of the tree, I need the value in td tag, Please help

[image]

url- https://stats.nba.com/players/bio/?sort=PLAYER_NAME&dir=-1

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/players/bio/?sort=PLAYER_NAME&dir=-1'
##url = input('Enter -')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

player = soup.find('nba-stat-table')
stat_table = player.find(class_='nba-stat-table__overlay')

for child in stat_table.children:
    c = child.findAll('td')
    #print(c)
print(player)
print(stat_table)
```

Comment: please share your code, then I will fix it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ1RB.png link to pic

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Thanks for the url.

The problem is that the page is using lazyloading. and you can not see the nba-stat-table without using javascript

Comment: Or you can use selenium

Comment: Ahh! Im only new and didn't know about lazy loading, much to learn, appreciate your quick responses, Ta

Answer (score 0):

The page loads the data from external source. You can use `requests` module to simulate this request.

For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/players/bio/?sort=PLAYER_NAME&dir=-1',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
}
url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight='
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for row in data['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']:
    print(('{:<20}'*len(row)).format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
203932              Aaron Gordon        1610612753          ORL                 24.0                6-8                 80                  235                 Arizona             USA                 2014                1                   4                   58                  14.4                7.6                 3.7                 -2.0                0.051               0.175               0.203               0.511               0.164               
1628988             Aaron Holiday       1610612754          IND                 23.0                6-0                 72                  185                 UCLA                USA                 2018                1                   23                  58                  9.4                 2.3                 3.3                 1.9                 0.015               0.076               0.188               0.517               0.191               
1627846             Abdel Nader         1610612760          OKC                 26.0                6-5                 77                  225                 Iowa State          Egypt               2016                2                   58                  48                  6.0                 1.9                 0.7                 -3.4                0.018               0.095               0.16                0.58                0.07                
1629690             Adam Mokoka         1610612741          CHI                 21.0                6-5                 77                  190                 None                France              Undrafted           Undrafted           Undrafted           11                  2.9                 0.9                 0.4                 17.1                0.057               0.029               0.11                0.538               0.043               
1629678             Admiral Schofield   1610612764          WAS                 23.0                6-5                 77                  241                 Tennessee           United Kingdom      2019                2                   42                  27                  3.1                 1.3                 0.5                 -4.9                0.018               0.092               0.123               0.514               0.068               
201143              Al Horford          1610612755          PHI                 34.0                6-9                 81                  240                 Florida             Dominican Republic  2007                1                   3                   60                  12.0                6.9                 4.1                 3.5                 0.05                0.17                0.174               0.526               0.185               
202329              Al-Farouq Aminu     1610612753          ORL                 29.0                6-8                 80                  220                 Wake Forest         USA                 2010                1                   8                   18                  4.3                 4.8                 1.2                 -5.4                0.053               0.158               0.127               0.395               0.088               
202692              Alec Burks          1610612755          PHI                 28.0                6-6                 78                  214                 Colorado            USA                 2011                1                   12                  59                  15.1                4.4                 2.9                 -8.3                0.025               0.134               0.23                0.549               0.178               
1629346             Alen Smailagic      1610612744          GSW                 19.0                6-10                82                  215                 None                Serbia              2019                2                   39                  14                  4.2                 1.9                 0.9                 -3.0                0.077               0.11                0.175               0.61                0.133               
1627936             Alex Caruso         1610612747          LAL                 26.0                6-5                 77                  186                 Texas A&M           USA                 Undrafted           Undrafted           Undrafted           58                  5.4                 1.9                 1.8                 10.3                0.014               0.088               0.136               0.538               0.128               
203458              Alex Len            1610612758          SAC                 27.0                7-0                 84                  250                 Maryland            Ukraine             2013                1                   5                   49                  8.3                 6.0                 1.0                 -5.6                0.096               0.195               0.178               0.596               0.085               
1628035             Alfonzo McKinnie    1610612739          CLE                 27.0                6-7                 79                  215                 None                USA                 Undrafted           Undrafted           Undrafted           40                  4.6                 2.8                 0.4                 -7.4                0.061               0.131               0.147               0.493               0.032               
1628993             Alize Johnson       1610612754          IND                 24.0                6-7                 79                  212                 Missouri State      USA                 2018                2                   50                  13                  1.4                 1.4                 0.2                 4.7                 0.119               0.204               0.142               0.51                0.045               
203459              Allen Crabbe        1610612750          MIN                 28.0                6-5                 77                  212                 California          USA                 2013                2                   31                  37                  4.6                 2.1                 0.9                 -15.0               0.014               0.098               0.122               0.47                0.073               
1629019             Allonzo Trier       1610612752          NYK                 24.0                6-4                 76                  200                 Arizona             USA                 Undrafted           Undrafted           Undrafted           24                  6.5                 1.2                 1.2                 -11.1               0.018               0.078               0.208               0.62                0.164               
1628518             Amile Jefferson     1610612753          ORL                 27.0                6-9                 81                  222                 Duke                USA                 Undrafted           Undrafted           Undrafted           18                  0.8                 1.3                 0.2                 8.5                 0.112               0.163               0.129               0.372               0.078               

...and so on.
```